# C++ iterator traversing

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

How can I get the next/previous iterator in a loop without modifying the current iterator? I cannot use either `operator++` or `operator--` as that would disturb the actual iteration of the loop.

If I were iterating over array indices `i`, I could say `A[i+1] = A[i]` without actually modifying `i`. How can I do the equivalent for iterators?

Comment: `std::vector` tagged, was `*(it + 1)` a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could say `A[i+1] = A[i]` without actually modifying `i`

The syntax is the same for random-access iterators (like that of `std::vector`):

```
iterator + 1  // next
```

and

```
iterator - 1  // previous
```

For a non-random-access iterator (or if you want something generic) use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
std::next(iterator)  // next
```

and

```
std::prev(iterator)  // previous
```

Answer (score 3):

If C++11, use [`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
auto it = ...;
auto next_it = std::next(it); // doesn't modify 'it'
```

If C++03, write your own `std::next()` based off of [`std::advance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt next(ForwardIt it,
               typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}
```

Note that if your iterator is a random access iterator, you could do the same thing you do for your array index. That is:

```
auto next_it = it + 1;
```

Comment: mine is a random access (vector) so suppose i want to replace the next position with the current element will this work?
it+1=*it;

Comment: @Bijeetchatterjee You mean `*(it+1) = *it;`.

Comment: NO i mean (it+1)=*it;

Comment: @Bijeetchatterjee Well that's totally wrong. `it + 1` is an (rvalue) iterator. It isn't assignable to at all. Even if it were,`*it` is an lvalue of the underlying type of the container. That assignment isn't going to work. But `*(it + 1)` is both an lvalue and of the right type.